# Error updating database! table or view does not exist

Tags: jquery, database, mybatis

I have this query

```
<update id="updateRow">
    update
      ROW
    set
      DISPLAY_ID = #{displayId}
    <where>
      <include refid="rowCriteria" />
    </where>
</update>

 <sql id="rowCriteria">
  <if test="criteria.displayId} != null">
     DISPLAY_ID=#{criteria.displayId}
  </if>
  <if test="criteria.id != null">
    and ID=#{criteria.id}
  </if>
 </sql>
```

and where is executed

```
 Preparing: update ROW set DISPLAY_ID = ? WHERE ID=? 

 Parameters: 72312(Long), 72991(Long)
```

i get this error

#### The error may involve defaultParameterMap

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: update           ROW set           DISPLAY_ID = ?          WHERE  ID=?

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

but if I delete 'and' from a criteria ID

```
 <sql id="rowCriteria">
  <if test="criteria.displayId} != null">
    DISPLAY_ID=#{criteria.displayId}
  </if>
  <if test="criteria.id != null">
    ID=#{criteria.id}
  </if>
 </sql>
```

the query run correct and the update is executed

My question is why sometimes the update run correctly if I have the **and key** in criteria and sometimes I get that error ?

Comment: I would suggest to enable queries logging in mybatis and check them for cases when it works and when it does not. Something does not match in your description. The query you say causes problems does not have any `AND` so removing that `AND` can't help.

Comment: In both cases with `AND` or without `AND` the query print is the same `update ROW set DISPLAY_ID = ? WHERE ID=?  ` is ok, but in case of criteria has `AND` i get that error. 
That's why I find it very strange. I think it could be a configuration issue, but I still can not find a solution

Comment: The mybatis log for two cases, as well as full config for two cases is needed. You wrote that you 'only' removed `and` but the definitions for `<sql id="rowCriteria">` differs not only in `and` so something still does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Remove the `}` that is in excess.
- Prefix every condition with `AND`. The < where > tag will remove the first one always.

  AND DISPLAY_ID=#{criteria.displayId}
    
    
      and ID=#{criteria.id}